# R: Filtering nodes with xpath

Tags: r, parsing, xpath, xml2

I am trying to parse an html document with R. There is an node I want to grab but within the node there are some information I just don't need.

For example:

```
<div class="content">
 <h3>Titel</h3>
 <p>content</p>
 <p>content</p>
 <ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want all the content and also the list. I don't need the title. So normally I would grab it with this code:

```
grabIt <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html, xpath="//div[@class='content']//text()
                       [not(ancestor-or-self::div[@class='content']//h3)]"))
```

This usually works fine. But here the "[not(ancestor-or-self"-Line filters out all the content. I think its because I am filtering out something within the node I am trying to grab. The code work correctly in those instances, where the title or any other information I don't need are in separate node like this:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="Titel">Title</div>  #difference
 <p>content</p>
 <p>content</p>
 <ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Another idea I have got is this:

```
grabIt <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html, xpath="//div[@class='content']//p//text()"))
```

But the problem is, that I cannot grab the paragraph and the list simultaneously.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example where your code works correctly and incorrectly. Without this we cannot help you.

Comment: The `li` closing tags are incorrectly formatted; they should be `</li>`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I think my problem lies within the xpath-line. When I define the content R doesn't just filter out the `<h3>` but it filters everything within the `<div class="content">` out. So my question is I guess: how do I exclude the `<h3>`?

Comment: I'm not sure why not just do it in two calls, but you could do it like `library(rvest) ; html %>% read_html() %>% { lapply(c('p', 'li'), function(x){html_nodes(., x)}) } %>% lapply(html_text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath :

`//div[@class='content']/*[not(name()='h3')][name()='p']/text() | //div[@class='content']/*[not(name()='h3')]/*[name()='li']/text()`

It gives :

```
'content'
'content'
'List'
'List'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much :)